# Publishing Angular Project not reading from pakage.json using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, publish, package.json

I am trying to publish my visual studio project on angular 2(generated using default template), I have changed some versions of npm but while publishing it executes the code npm install and bring backs the old versions. I think it is not reading from my package.json. What is the solution for this?

I have the following issue initially https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7702 to resolve this I had to updae my versions accordingly as suggested, But while publishing it reverts back to old version and I get the error listed in the ablove link.
[image]

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/common": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.43",
    "tsickle": "^0.23.5",
    "tslib": "^1.7.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the subject, but for others to be able to analyse, would you please provide additional information? Any kind of logs, warning displayed, etc?

Comment: can post the project structure with the package.json file that would help everyone to understand if there is something wrong. Just asking it does not work wont find you any help.